# pg_dump individual tables -- possible to do in a loop?

Tags: perl, postgresql, pg-dump

I have been tasked with creating pg_dump files for a db on which there are over 50 tables. I know how to do this manually via the psql command line, but I believe there must be a faster way than doing each one by hand.  Any suggestions on how to it programmatically? For example, can a perl script call pg_dump?

Comment: You really need to dump each table on it's own? How do you know which table to restore in what order without breaking foreign key constraints?

Comment: correction: I was just dumping table schema, not the full table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then following Bash script should be sufficient:

```
#!/bin/bash

for table in `psql -Atc "\dt" | cut -d '|' -f2`   
do   
   pg_dump -Fp -t $table -f $table.dump;
done
```

It gets list of all tables within some database and execute `pg_dump -t` for each of them.

Here is Perl equivalent if you prefer:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

@tables = qx/psql -Atc "\\dt" | cut -d '|' -f2/;
foreach (@tables)
{
    chomp($_);
    system("pg_dump -Fp -t $_ -f $_.dump");
}
```

Comment: That will only catch the tables that are in the search_path of the user making the query.  A better approach might be to use `
    SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
    c.relname as "Name",
    pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) as "Owner"
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
    WHERE c.relkind IN ('r','')
      AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
      AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
;` to get the table list.

Comment: @gsiems: You're right about [`search_path`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html) (more strictly this is about [`pg_table_is_visible`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-SCHEMA-TABLE) in `\dt`), but this looks like overkill for me, unless these table are spreaded in multiple schemas (and search_path is unset to handle this), then of course your solution is more comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks, the perl script sent me in the right direction, had not been aware of the system(); command before.

Comment: good. It works (bash). The only change made is to add namespace to \dt command. Otherwise only default namespace is listed

Answer (score 0):

If your tables are organized into various schemas, then perhaps the following will work for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $database_name = 'book_library';

my $query = <<"EOT";
SELECT  n.nspname as table_schema,
        c.relname as table_name
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
        LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
    WHERE c.relkind IN ('r','')
        AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
        AND n.nspname NOT LIKE '^pg_%'
    ;
EOT

$query =~ s/\n\s*/ /g;

my @results = `echo  "$query" | psql -At $database_name`;
foreach (@results) {
    chomp;
    my ($schema, $table) = split /\|/, $_;
    next unless ($schema && $table);
    my $cmd = "pg_dump -U postgres -Fp -t $schema.$table -f $schema.$table.dump $database_name";
    system($cmd);
}
```

Note that you'll have to set the $database_name variable appropriately and there is the assumption that you are using a .pgpass file.

Answer (score -3):

pg_dumpall is the tool to dump your entire db

http://www.postgresql.org/files/documentation/books/aw_pgsql/node265.html

Comment: Thanks I was aware of pg_dumpall but I want to pg_dump the tablesinto individual scripts.